# See live results of command line expression in the terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, command-line

I often find myself crafting a long bash or zsh command that just isn't quite long enough to be a script in and of itself. For example, when I'm debugging a sed expression, I often change one character and re-run my command to see how the output changes:

```
$ echo "123 eyes on me" | sed -E 's/[[:alnum:]*]//'
23 eyes on me
$ echo "123 eyes on me" | sed -E 's/[[:alnum:]]*//'
 eyes on me
$ echo "123 eyes on me" | sed -E 's/[[:alnum:] ]*//'

$ echo "123 eyes on me" | sed -E 's/[[:digit:] ]*//'
eyes on me
```

Even with knowledge of `vi-mode` and proficiency in the terminal, it is cumbersome to edit the previous command and re-run it each time. I'd rather just edit the parameters in place and see its effect live.

There are some websites that provide tools like this for specific use cases, for example with regex matching:

[image]

Other examples include JSON linters, calculators, or YAML parsers. However these all suffer from multiple problems:

- they are not generic and portable to developing commands as a whole, what if I want to pipe regex output to `tr`, and then later select the third column with `awk`?
- may behave differently than my command in the terminal
- it runs in a browser online rather than in my terminal
- not open source

Is there some way to live-develop a command line expression in my terminal and see the output as I am typing it out?

Comment: I do it like this, create a script usually `/tmp/1.sh` which I edit in one console and in the other I run `watch -n1 bash -xc /tmp/1.sh`. That way each time the script is saved, it takes one second for watch to reload the output. Usually I split screen for the two consoles to see the output refresh.

Comment: To the close voters: I can see why you'd think this is asking for a specific tool. That certainly wouldn't be an appropriate question for SO, but it's not really what I'm asking here and I'll update the question to reflect that. What I really want is a generic way to see live results of a command in bash - this is a question of how to use common programming tools like bash, command lines, and terminals. I'm not looking for tool recommendations here, I'm looking for ways to reproduce the example web-app functionality with vanilla POSIX tools.

Answer (score 0):

I typically just put my code into a `sed.sh`:

```
echo "testing 123" | sed 's/123/456/'
```

And then in a terminal watch the execution of this file:

```
watch -n1 './sed.sh'
```

Comment: combine this with `sed -Ef script.sed` where the sed script can be edited independently.